# Can a logged in user restore its ~/Library folder from a Time Machine backup made with a previous version of the OS?

Tags: time-machine, restore, user-account, carbon-copy-cloner

The full story: I have a clone of my old MBP drive which had Yosemite installed. I now have a new MBP with macOS Sierra on it. I tried to transfer the data from my old Mac to the new one using Migration Assistant, but it froze while importing the Applications. I also tried importing just my user account, but it was so slow that I cancelled the procedure, and decided to use Carbon Copy Cloner to finish the work. CCC had problems with permissions on some folders in my ~/Library folder however, and it did not seem to succeed importing everything. Now, my question is three-fold:

1. Will I have more luck if I restore my ~/Library folder from a Time Machine backup? Or will it also have the same permission problems?
2. My Time Machine backup is from a Yosemite installation. If I restore my ~/Library folder from that backup on a macOS Sierra machine, will I run into troubles? I am thinking about settings that might be specific to macOS Sierra here that I would be loosing by overwriting my ~/Library folder.
3. Will it work to restore my ~/Library folder from Time Machine while I am logged in? I mean, won't some of these files be in use and impossible to overwrite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you done anything on the Sierra install that you wouldn't want overwritten? I've never tried restoring between different versions myself, but my guess is that it wouldn't be an issue—it'd just upgrade everything it needed to when you next logged in.

As for doing it *while* you are logged in—I wouldn't try it. I would either log in under a different administrator account, if you have one (but this might result in permissions problems), or log out, then borrow someone else's machine and log in over SSH. That way you won't have background processes writing stuff to your Library folder as you're trying to copy it.

---

**This is for Time Machine. It may not restore everything—see below!**

- Borrow a friend's Mac (sorry, but Windows machines won't work) and open Terminal.

**If your backup drive is locked:**

- Connect your backup drive and unlock it if necessary.
- Open Terminal.
- See below, starting with the `ssh` command, and replace `~/Library` with `/Volumes/disk/Backups.backupdb/machine-name/Latest/Macintosh\ HD/Users/user/Library` where `disk` is the name of the backup disk, `machine-name` is the name of the old machine, and `user` is your username, as in the SSH command. Any spaces will have to be preceded with backslashes, as with "Macintosh\ HD". You can hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> while typing a path segment and it will autocomplete it for you, including escaping things as necessary (the backslash thing). **Stop before the `chmod` command**, as you didn't do anything to your friend's Library folder and don't need to undo it. (Plus, if for some reason they *wanted* something in their Library folder to be read-only, they might get mad at you!)

**If your backup drive is not locked (hopefully it is, but just in case):**

- Do the same thing as above, except connect the backup drive to the new machine (without logging in!) and remove the `user@machine.local:` bit from the transfer. Also do the transfer **while still logged in to the remote machine**. You can then also use `~` in place of `/Users/user` (but don't replace this with `/Volumes/...`). The above method works just fine, but this one is faster.

---

### **An important note!**

I'm not completely sure about this, but **Time Machine may not back up everything in ~/Library**. If you find something missing and still have the old machine around, I would use that to transfer the files:

- Boot up both machines and connect them to the same network. Do **not** log in on the new machine, or log out if you are logged in.
- Log into the old machine, and open Terminal.
- Type `chmod -R -w ~/Library`. This will prevent the old system from modifying the folder as you're copying it. **From here on out, until you undo this with `chmod -R +w ~/Library`, preferences will not be saved.** Some other things might not be saved either; it's just a good idea not to do any work on either machine while this is going on.
- Type `ssh user@machine.local`, where `user` is your username on the new machine (the name of your home folder, not your full name), `machine` is your new machine name, and `local` is the TLD of your local network. It may be `local` (mine is), but may also be something else. It might say something to the effect of "authenticity cannot be verified", but if you're on a home network you probably don't have to worry about this. You'll need to enter your login password (for the new machine) when it asks you.

  - You are now logged in to the remote machine. Type `mv ~/Library ~/.Trash/Library` to trash the folder you're about to replace.

    - If you don't have enough disk space to keep the old version around, you can use `rm -rv ~/Library` instead. **Be very careful with `rm`**, however! It deletes files immediately, **without asking for confirmation**. I wouldn't recommend doing this unless absolutely necessary, as then you won't be able to restore if there's a problem.
  - Type ⌃D to log out of the remote system. If that doesn't work (although it should), use `exit`.
- Type `rsync -rlptgDEHP --stats ~/Library user@machine.local:/Users/user/Library`, substituting as above. This is the actual copy; it will most likely take a very long time. If you need to stop, just hit ⌃C to cancel the transfer. When you pick up again, it will have to go through the "building file list" process all over again but the actual sending process should pick up where you left off.

  - You can add `z` to the `-rlptgDEHP` bit if you have a slow local network (which is kind of unlikely, but...). This will make rsync compress everything before sending it across the network, although it'll take time to compress it before sending it and decompress it at the other end.
- **After the transfer is complete** and you've tested it to make sure nothing broke, type `chmod -R +w ~/Library` (on the local machine). This will make it writable again.

  - **Edit**: You should do this on the new machine as well, so you'll be able to save preferences and things there.

---

A small note about security (this shouldn't really matter at home, but it might elsewhere):

Rsync uses a remote-shell program for the transfer; if the remote-shell program isn't secure, I doubt the transfer would be. It *should* use SSH, which is secure, but according to the manual, it can be configured to use something else:

> For remote transfers, a modern rsync uses ssh for its communications, but it may have been configured to use a different remote shell by default, such as rsh or remsh.
>
> You can also specify any remote shell you like, either by using the -e command line option, or by setting the RSYNC_RSH environment variable.

So if you want to force it to use SSH, use `RSYNC_RSH='ssh' rsync ...`

This only matters for network connections; it doesn't matter with the "TM drive not locked" method, as SSH is definitely used there.

Comment: Actually, I don't have access to my older MBP. It is a late 2011 model with the graphics chip problem, and it won't boot anymore, or rarely boot should I say. But I was able to clone its disk before it became inoperable, and I can connect this disk to my new MBP, so your solutions should still work. And I also have the Time Machine backup. So, I'll give it a try.

Comment: My old MacBook Pro (early 2011) had the graphics chip problem–and even with it not showing the login screen, I could still access it using SFTP, and presumably SSH as well. (Apple then fixed it for free!) But it's good that you cloned the disk (which should still work anyway, since it's the graphics card that broke). Good luck!

Comment: Apple replaced my logic board twice. The last time was in July 2016, but the problem reappeared last month. Now, they consider 2011 MBP's as "vintage", and they don't make the parts anymore so it cannot be fixed. Actually they want us to believe those machines are vintage. To me, a Commodore 64 or an Apple II is vintage. Outside from that, my 2011 MBP was still doing a fine job. Apple did not impress me with that one.

Comment: Ouch. :( Sorry to hear that, hope the new Mac works just as well.

Comment: In fact, I don't really need to use SSH. I just rebooted my new MBP in single user mode (Command-S while turning one the MBP), and I logged in as a different user. I then remounted my internal drive to be read-write, mounted my external drive, renamed Library folder of the user I want to recover and I issued the rsync command.

Comment: I did not really have to login as a different user, now that I think about it, since the Library folder is most probably not used when logging in single user mode which gives you only a terminal window. I hope the rsync options will keep the original file attributes and not make my current user the owner of the files.

Comment: Thanks, I should have mentioned that in the post. And yes, that's what rsync's `-p` option does. I use the same command to back up an external drive to another one.

Comment: Thanks for your solution! It put me on the right track. Since I logged in in Single User Mode to issue the rsync command, all my files were owned by root. I would have had to add the 'o' flag to the rsync command in order to avoid this:

`rsync -rlptgoDEHP --stats /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/<my user>/Library /Users/<my user>`

Comment: Also, one should not specify `Library` in the destination otherwise the result is a Library folder inside the Library folder.

In order to fix the ownership problem, I used `chown` to make my user the owner of the Library folder and its content. I hope no file in there needs to be owned by another user...

Comment: One last thing, rsync is verbose by default, and it outputs information about each file it copies. I believe this slows the process, so I also used the -q flag to make the rsync silent. The drawback is that I had no feedback about what was happening, but I just let it run the whole day, and when I came back from work, the copy was done.

Comment: Oh, yes. I'm _still_ not sure exactly when folder copies will result in overwriting the original folder, vs. putting it inside the original folder. In my answer I sidestepped the issue by trashing the original folder before the move. And I didn't even think about `-o` and single-user mode.

Comment: Also, on verbosity – it was being verbose because of the `-P` option. It's the same as `--partial --progress`, so you can just use `--partial` instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66345/discussion-between-seaturtle-and-jean-francois-beauchamp).